# Error: call revert exception Uniswap getAmountsOut

Tags: solidity, contract-development, hardhat, uniswap, contract-debugging

I am trying to build a bot that can perform tri-arbitrage trades and I ran into an issue that I don't really understand when trying to interact with the Uniswap v2 router in my contract to estimate a trade.

I am running this on a hardhat forked Ethereum mainnet and this is the error I'm currently getting;

In my terminal

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="estimateTriDexTrade(address,address,address,address,address,address,uint256)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

In the hardhat node console

```
 Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
  at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xd9e1ce17f2641f24ae83637ab66a2cca9c378b9f)
  at FlashLoanAb.getAmountOutMin (contracts/FlashLoanAb.sol:93)
  at FlashLoanAb.estimateTriDexTrade (contracts/FlashLoanAb.sol:110)
```

This the UniswapRouter interfaces I'm using in my contract

```
interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function getAmountsOut(
        uint256 amountIn,
        address[] memory path
    ) external view returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
    function token0() external view returns (address);

    function token1() external view returns (address);

    function swap(
        uint256 amount0Out,
        uint256 amount1Out,
        address to,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external;
}
```

These are the function calls

```
    function getAmountOutMin(
        address router,
        address _tokenIn,
        address _tokenOut,
        uint256 _amount
    ) public view returns (uint256) {
        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = _tokenIn;
        path[1] = _tokenOut;
        uint256[] memory amountOutMins = IUniswapV2Router(router).getAmountsOut(
            _amount,
            path
        );
        return amountOutMins[path.length - 1];
    }
```

```
  function estimateTriDexTrade(
        address _router1,
        address _router2,
        address _router3,
        address _token1,
        address _token2,
        address _token3,
        uint256 _amount
    ) external view returns (uint256) {
        console.log(_amount);
        uint amtBack1 = getAmountOutMin(_router1, _token1, _token2, _amount);
        uint amtBack2 = getAmountOutMin(_router2, _token2, _token3, amtBack1);
        uint amtBack3 = getAmountOutMin(_router3, _token3, _token1, amtBack2);
        return amtBack3;
    }
```

These are the router addresses I'm

```
  "routers": [
    {
      "dex": "1inch",
      "address": "0x1111111254EEB25477B68fb85Ed929f73A960582"
    },
    {
      "dex": "sushiswap",
      "address": "0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F"
    },
    {
      "dex": "uniswap",
      "address": "0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d"
    }
  ],
```

I followed the link suggested in the error logs and read about the CALL_EXCEPTION error code in the ethers documentation but the common causes don't seem to apply here, tried the suggested debugging solution and I can access other functions in the contract just these that are throwing error.

I'm still kinda wet behind the ears when it comes to solidity and blockchain so I don't really understand what it is that I'm doing wrong. Am I interacting with the contract wrongly, or passing the wrong variables? Can someone please enlighten me, thanks.

[image: contract in IDE]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure, but it looks like the address you have for sushiSwap in your router addresses isn't being recognised - evident from the error  `at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xd9e1ce17f2641f24ae83637ab66a2cca9c378b9f)`.

I would try to check the address is correct, and if still facing problems, omit it from your router addresses and/or change the places where it's being invoked, perhaps at lines 93 & 110 (given error codes).

Comment: I have confirmed that this is the correct sushiswap router and Its not just sushiswap, all the dex throws this error and Those lines are empty spaces after the functions I dont know why its referencing those. I would add a screenshot of the contract in my IDE